# ajaxsubmit is giving me an error with some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, jquery.form.js

I have page using Coldfusion and jquery and I am trying to get a form submitted using ajaxSubmit. I am finding that with some text I get an error and I do not understand why.

I have created a demo page at http://www.demo.adreflex.com/debug_edit.cfm and http://www.demo.adreflex.com/debug_edit.cfm?dbg=3 that illustrates my problem.

The file, SaveInlineEdit_dbg.cfm, exists but its contents are empty.

When you access this page using the first link you get the following error:

> Forbidden  You don't have permission to access
>   /inc/SaveInlineEdit_dbg.cfm on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When you access the page using the second link everything works fine. The only difference is the text being submitted in the form.

I am hoping someone can shed some light on this and help me fix this problem.

Below is a copy of the code found in debug_edit.cfm

```
<cfparam name="url.dbg" default="1">
<link type="text/css" href="jqueryui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jqueryui\/1.12.2\/jquery.min.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script><script src="jqueryui\/js\/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js" type="text\/javascript" ><\/script>;');
</script>

<script src="jqueryui/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<div id="formstate"></div>
<form name="InlineForm" id="InlineForm" style="margin:0px;" action="/inc/SaveInlineEdit_dbg.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <cfif url.dbg eq 1>
        <input type="hidden" name="PageContent" id="PageContent" size="200" value='<p>CONVERT MORE with search engine optimization and responsive design.</p>' /><br>

        <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="PageContent_disp" id="PageContent_disp" size="200" value='<p>CONVERT MORE with search engine optimization and responsive design.</p>' /><br>
    <cfelse>

        <input type="hidden" name="PageContent" id="PageContent" size="200" value='<p>responsive design</p>' /><br>

        <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="PageContent_disp" id="PageContent_disp" size="200" value='<p>responsive design</p>' /><br>

    </cfif>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
var optionsSaveDoc = 
{ 
    error: errorHandlerSaveDoc,
    success: callbackSaveDoc 
}; 


//callback handler for form submit
$("#InlineForm").submit(function(e)
{
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(optionsSaveDoc); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    return false; 
});

$("#InlineForm").submit(); //Submit the FORM

function callbackSaveDoc(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{
    $('div#formstate').html('It worked');
}

function errorHandlerSaveDoc(msg)
{
    $('div#formstate').html(msg.responseText);
    console.log(msg.responseText);
}
</script>
```

Comment: weird.. if that helps, it actually displays permission error when you have `dgb=1` in the url too, so it seems related to what happens when it has this value (which is default). Does it still 403 when you copy the 2 inputs from the second alternative into the first (in `<cfif url.dbg eq 1>`)?

Comment: The error only happens when the text that I am trying to submit to the form contains: _<p>CONVERT MORE with search engine optimization and responsive design.</p>_. All other text works fine. I am just using the parameter url.dbg as a way to have one page but display 2 different versions where one works and the other doesn't

Comment: Did you try other html tags and/or other angle brackets?

Comment: others html tags and/or angle brackets work. For some reason this particular text does not work. Other text between _<p> .. </p>_ also works

Comment: have you tried to put the `$("#InlineForm").submit();` inside a `$(document).ready`? that can't hurt even if that doesn't solve the problem.. Maybe with `dataType: 'json'` in your options? it seems that the default is `null` but i don't know what it corresponds to..